# Why Hibernate Lazy Loading do not release database connection?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-connection, lazy-loading

Why hibernate(JPA) do not release database connection after lazy loading query is executed?
On example below, if I comments this "--System.out.println(user1.getUserOwner());" and execute JMeter test with twice users amount(500*2=1000 users) works.
Why lazy loading captures database connections?
Many connections opened error is throw.

I'm using:

- Hibernate 4.3.6.Final;
- Primefaces 5.0.0;
- CDI Weld 2.2.4.Final;
- JSF 2.2.8;

**EMProducer.java**

```
public class EMProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String PESISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "pfac";

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PESISTENCE_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public EntityManagerFactory create() {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PESISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    }

    public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        factory.close();
    }

    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return extractEntityManager(emf);
    }

    private EntityManager extractEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }

}
```

**test.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
>
<f:view>
<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    #{testView}
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**Managed View**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestView implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    private void inicialize(){
        User user1 = this.entityManager.find(User.class, 1);
        System.out.println(user1.getUserOwner());
    }

}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = User.TABLE_NAME, schema = User.SCHEMA_NAME)
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String SCHEMA_NAME = "public";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tb_user";
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "sq_"+TABLE_NAME;

    private Integer id;
    private User userOwner;
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE_NAME, schema=SCHEMA_NAME, sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE_NAME)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_owner", nullable = false, updatable=false)
    @NotNull
    public User getUserOwner() {
        return userOwner;
    }
    public void setUserOwner(User userOwner) {
        this.userOwner = userOwner;
    }

    @Column(name = "ds_name")
    @Size(min=5, max=100)
    @NotNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (!getId().equals(other.getId())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getId();
        return result;
    }

}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">
        <persistence-unit name="pfac" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
            <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username"  value="postgres" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres" /> 
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2" />
                <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16" />
                <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Comment: I have a same problem.When I change the LAZY to EAGER the problem goes away! Why?

Answer (score 1):

The EntityManager should be injected using:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pfac")
```

not with the @Inject annotation.

The EntityManager is context-bound, you can have it associated to the current thread transaction or use an application-scope persistence context. [The connection release mode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-connection-release) is always related to the current transaction configuration: JDBC or JTA.

In your case you are using JDBC resource-local transactions, yet you configured:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement" />
```

which you'd normally use for JTA aggressive release modes. In works with JDBC connections but it's not what it was meant for.

Because you are using DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl it measn Hibernate will use an internal connection pool to handle JDBC connections.

After each statement, the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider#closeConnection(Connection conn) is going to be called.

For DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  this is how it looks like:

```
@Override
public void closeConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    if (conn == null) {
        return;
    }

    this.connections.offer( conn );
}
```

So the connections are not closed, but they return to the pool and that's why they are not closed. You need to close the EntityManagerFactory to close the internal connection pool and then all JDBC connections are going to be physically closed.

Comment: Hi @Vlad Mihalcea, I'm using tomcat.
After "PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE" listener, I called "begin and rollback" transaction from injected entitymanager then the connection was finally release. I think that this is an Hibernate bug.

Comment: If you are using Open Session In View then you must make sure both transactions commit/rollback and the session gets closed too.